# Vue.js custom directive: $refs is empty

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

**Background**

I created a custom directive (to detect clicks outside of an element) by following this guide: https://tahazsh.com/detect-outside-click-in-vue.

Element:

```
<button
 id='burger'
 ref='burger'
 class='burger button is-white'>
 <span class='burger-top' aria-hidden='true' style='pointer-events: none;'></span>

 <span class='burger-bottom' aria-hidden='true' style='pointer-events: none;'></span>
</button>
```

Directive:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

let handleOutsideClick;

Vue.directive('outside', {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();

        const { handler, exclude } = binding.value;

        let clickedOnExcludedEl = false;

        exclude.forEach((refName) => {
          if (!clickedOnExcludedEl) {
            const excludedEl = vnode.context.$refs[refName]
            console.log(vnode.context.$refs);
            clickedOnExcludedEl = excludedEl.contains(e.target);
          }
        });

        if (!el.contains(e.target) && !clickedOnExcludedEl) {
          vnode.context[handler]();
        }
      };
      document.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);
      document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleOutsideClick);
    }, 50);
  },
  unbind() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);
    document.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleOutsideClick);
  },
});
```

Note that I have had to add `setTimeout`.

Using the directive in a sidebar component:

```
<div
  id='sidebar'
  class='sidebar-container'
  v-show='toggleSideBar'
  v-outside='{
    handler: "close",
    exclude: [
      "burger",
    ],
  }'>
  <div class='sidebar-content'>
    // other content
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

`$refs` is empty, even though the element clearly has a `ref`.

This is clear also from `console.log(vnode.context.$refs);`.

Notably, getting the element by id works:

```
        exclude.forEach((id) => {
          if (!clickedOnExcludedEl) {
            const excludedEl = document.getElementById(id);
            clickedOnExcludedEl = excludedEl.contains(e.target);
          }
        });
```

**Question**

Why is `$refs` empty when the element clearly exists and can be accessed by id?

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Could you show us the complete tag markup that is taking this directive?

Comment: Updated my post. The burger is in the navbar. Clicking on it will open/close the sidebar. The point of the directive here is to allow the sidebar to be closed by clicking outside of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way this code is currently written the `ref='burger'` and `v-outside` must be in the same template.

The key line is:

```js
const excludedEl = vnode.context.$refs[refName]
```

`vnode.context` will refer to the Vue instance for your sidebar component. The `$refs` must be defined in the template for that component.

`$refs` are local to a particular Vue instance. By 'Vue instance' I mean the component instance, if that terminology is any clearer. So the sidebar will have one set of `$refs` and the navbar will have its own set of `$refs`.

Based on the comment under the question it would seem that the button is currently defined in the template for the navbar component. So you'll end up with a `burger` ref in the navbar's `$refs` but the directive is looking for it inside the sidebar's `$refs`.

The way that directive is written needs a template a bit like this:

```html
<div>
  <div
    v-outside='{
      handler: "close",
      exclude: ["burger"]
    }'
  >
    ...  
  </div>
  <button ref='burger'>...</button>
</div>
```

Here the `v-outside` and `ref='burger'` are both in the same template so everything will work fine. As soon as you move the button to a different template it won't be able to find it.

Using an `id` and `document.getElementById` is a very different scenario. Element ids are registered globally. It doesn't matter where the element is in the DOM, so long as it is present it will be found.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense. I guess that I will just continue to use ids in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It is so, because your `ref` is not what `refName` is.

Your ref is "burger" but refName is a `exclude` property given to `v-closable` which you then restructure.

In the tutorial you linked to, `refName`  is `button`. So I'm assuming it is the same in your code.

Make sure both `ref="burger"` and

`v-closable="{ exclude: ['burger'], // this is your refName handler: 'onClose' }"`

are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Everything is correct, and I have updated my original post to show this. The issue is that `$refs` is empty (even though it should not be), so `.contains` fails.

Comment: Try switching outside single quoates `'` to double `"`, and double inside to single.